# IReactiveDerivedList broken after deserialization

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net, reactiveui

When I create a ViewModel with a `ReactiveList` and an `IReactiveDerivedList` and then serialize and deserialize it using Json.net, the derived list seems to be broken. What am I doing wrong?

The viewmodel:

```
[DataContract]
public class TestViewModel : ReactiveObject
{
    [DataMember]
    public ReactiveList<int> List { get; } = new ReactiveList<int>();

    public IReactiveDerivedList<int> DerivedList { get; }

    public TestViewModel()
    {
        //DerivedList contains all elements of List that are greater than 0.
        DerivedList = List.CreateDerivedCollection(v => v, v => v > 0);
    }
}
```

The serialization test:

```
private void Example()
{
    TestViewModel vm = new TestViewModel();
    vm.List.Add(0);
    vm.List.Add(1);

    //vm.DerivedList now has 1 item

    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(vm);
    TestViewModel clone = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TestViewModel>(json);

    //vm.DerivedList now has 1 item
    //clone.DerivedList now has 1 item

    vm.List.Add(1);
    clone.List.Add(1);

    //vm.DerivedList now has 2 items
    //clone.DerivedList now has 1 item
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue here is that when the ViewModel is deserialized, the ReactiveList used as the source for the derived list is also deserialized, which is where the problem lies.

When your TestViewModel is deserialized, the order of events goes something like this:

- The [ReactiveList constructor](https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/blob/26e96170eadcc56c7cbff5ab6246841ddb8bc581/src/ReactiveUI/ReactiveList.cs#L141) runs.  This [sets up](https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/blob/26e96170eadcc56c7cbff5ab6246841ddb8bc581/src/ReactiveUI/ReactiveList.cs#L158-L173) the observable backing fields.
- The TestViewModel constructor runs.  This sets up the derived collection, which subscribes to the observables on the ReactiveList.
- The [ReactiveList "OnDeserialized"](https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/blob/26e96170eadcc56c7cbff5ab6246841ddb8bc581/src/ReactiveUI/ReactiveList.cs#L149-L150) callback runs.  This [sets up](https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/blob/26e96170eadcc56c7cbff5ab6246841ddb8bc581/src/ReactiveUI/ReactiveList.cs#L158-L173) the observable backing fields *again*, overwriting their previous values.

The last step is where the issue occurs.  The derived collection is subscribed to the *old* observables, not the ones that are now being used by the ReactiveList.  One way to fix it would be to give the derived list property a private setter, implement a [deserialization callback](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.ondeserializedattribute?view=netframework-4.6), and create the derived list in that callback.

```
[DataContract]
public class TestViewModel : ReactiveObject
{
    [DataMember]
    public ReactiveList<int> List { get; } = new ReactiveList<int>();

    public IReactiveDerivedList<int> DerivedList { get; private set; }

    public TestViewModel()
    {
        SetupRx();
    }

    [OnDeserialized]
    internal void OnDeserialized(StreamingContext context)
    {
        SetupRx();
    }

    private void SetupRx()
    {
        DerivedList?.Dispose();
        DerivedList = List.CreateDerivedCollection(v => v, v => v > 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: After some more testing, it seems that even with this setup ReactiveList is kinda buggy. For example: if you replace integers with a viewmodel type in the example, and set the filter to a property of the VM type, the derived list breaks again. Setting ChangeTrackingEnabled to true in SetupRx() doesn't help. It does work when you first set ChangeTrackingEnabled to false, and then to true again. Internally, this is because _itemChanged is replaced in setupRx() of ReactiveList and toggling changetracking resets the bindings.

But this makes for some very ugly code